# How to set OnclickListener in recyclerView for going another activity

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener

**Hello everyone. I am new in android development. I am using room database and I set data in recyclerView. Now I am trying to Do when I click any recyclerview item then I need to go another activity.Anyone Please help me. **

**MainActivity RecyclerView Adding code**

```
 private fun setUpListOfDataIntoRecyclerView(registerList:ArrayList<registerEntity>,
                                                registerDao: registerDao){

        if(registerList.isNotEmpty()){
            var itemAdapter = MainAdapter(registerList)
            
            binding?.rvHappyPlaceList?.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
            binding?.rvHappyPlaceList?.adapter = itemAdapter
            binding?.rvHappyPlaceList?.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            binding?.noRecordText?.visibility = View.GONE
        }else{
            binding?.rvHappyPlaceList?.visibility = View.GONE
            binding?.noRecordText?.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }
    }
```

**MainAdapter**

```
class MainAdapter(val items: ArrayList<registerEntity>):
    RecyclerView.Adapter<MainAdapter.MainHolder>() {

    //step 2
    private var onClickListener: AdapterView.OnItemClickListener? = null

    inner class MainHolder(var binding: ItemHappyPlaceBinding): RecyclerView.
                           ViewHolder(binding.root) {
                                val llTitle = binding.tvTitle
                                 val llDescription = binding.tvDescription
                                  var llImage = binding.ivPlaceImage
                         }

    fun setOnClickListener(onClickListener: View.OnContextClickListener){
        this.onClickListener = onClickListener
    }



    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MainHolder, position: Int) {
        val item = items[position]
        holder.llTitle.text = item.title
        holder.llDescription.text = item.description
        holder.llImage.setImageURI(Uri.parse(item.image))
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you replace:

```
private var onClickListener: AdapterView.OnItemClickListener? = null
```

with this:

```
var onItemClick: (() -> Unit)? = null
```

You can also delete the fun setOnClickListener(..){}

And add in your MainHolder the binding.root.setOnClickListener{} like:

```
inner class MainHolder(var binding: ItemHappyPlaceBinding): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
  init {
    binding.root.setOnClickListener {
      onItemClick?.invoke()
    }
  }
  
  val llTitle = binding.tvTitle
  val llDescription = binding.tvDescription
  var llImage = binding.ivPlaceImage
}
```

Or if you prefer u can also add the onItemClick?.invoke() in the onBindViewHolder like:

```
  holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
    onItemClick?.invoke()
  }
```

And then in your activity, in fun setUpListOfDataIntoRecyclerView add:

```
var itemAdapter = MainAdapter(registerList)
itemAdapter.onItemClick = this::goToActivity()
```

And also add the goToActivity fun like:

```
fun goToActivity(){
  // launch the activity
}
```

Comment: binding.root.setOnClickListener {
    onItemClick?.invoke()
  }    ?It showing error and calling  expecting member declaration

Comment: i updated the answer, check the init{} on MainHolder @SabujAhmed

Comment: Thank you bro its working. Can you please explain it how it working

Comment: Its the basic implementation of the RecyclerView adapter, I recommend you check the oficial android example in github like: https://github.com/android/sunflower to increase your knowledge

Comment: Can you please add me your friend list. If you don't mind.

Comment: Sure, send a request! And don't forget to upvote and accept the answer with the Green checkmark!  @SabujAhmed

Comment: I have only 7 reputation that why upvote and chat not possible but can you please give me your any social account. And can you please give me sunflower project type github some knowledage improvement project which helped you to gain knowledge. I am new in this android platfrom so if you think I irratateing you then extremly sorry.